# Angular 1.3 data binding not working

Tags: angularjs, 2-way-object-databinding

I'm running into some problems with Angular 1.3.2

I'm expecting to see the formData object being populated with whatever is being typed in the input fields

I have the following code.

```
angular.module('formApp', [])

.controller('FormController', function ($scope, $http) {

  $scope.formData = {};

  $scope.processForm = function () {

  };

});

<div class="form-container" ng-app="formApp" ng-controller="FormController">
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <div id="name-group" class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Bruce Wayne" ng-model="formData.name">
            <span class="help-block"></span>
        </div>

        <div id="superhero-group" class="form-group">
            <label>Superhero Alias</label>
            <input type="text" name="superheroAlias" class="form-control" placeholder="Caped Crusader"
                   ng-model="formData.superheroAlias">
            <span class="help-block"></span>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span> Submit!
        </button>
    </form>

    <pre>
        {{ formData }}
    </pre>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ngcontroller="FormController" is ng-controller="FormController", right?, plus, if you can avoid set the controller on same tag of your ng-app its better.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the error you are showing, using Angular 1.3.2.  See http://plnkr.co/edit/xA3L4jE3Q48g5J1raGaI?p=preview

Comment: Seems my code is correct then, the problem must lie somewhere else...

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in your ngcontroller syntax. it should be [ng-controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)

```
<div class="form-container" ng-app="formApp" ng-controller="FormController">
```

Comment: I fixed that. That was due to a problem with copy pasting it into a 'code block'

Answer (score 0):

Copied your code and it is working, see below:

```js
angular.module('formApp', [])

.controller('FormController', function ($scope, $http) {

  $scope.formData = {};

  $scope.processForm = function () {

  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-container" ng-app="formApp" ng-controller="FormController">
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <div id="name-group" class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Bruce Wayne" ng-model="formData.name">
            <span class="help-block"></span>
        </div>

        <div id="superhero-group" class="form-group">
            <label>Superhero Alias</label>
            <input type="text" name="superheroAlias" class="form-control" placeholder="Caped Crusader"
                   ng-model="formData.superheroAlias">
            <span class="help-block"></span>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span> Submit!
        </button>
    </form>

    <pre>
        {{ formData }}
    </pre>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Correct, but as I said I'm on 1.3.2 and it doesn't work on that version. I checked the 1.2 > 1.3 migration docs but I can't seem to find what's wrong.